# I am a student and I having a problem with moving my cicles in in the fried egg challenge in code hs

Tags: java

I am a student and in class, we are doing graphic challenges. I am doing the fried egg challenge in CodeHS but my white circles won't move correctly and am having trouble with the positions.

I have already tried putting in different positions but it won't work

```
          var circleD = new Circle(eggRadius);
         circleD.setPosition(eggRadius,100);
         circleD.setColor(eggWhiteColor);
         var x = getWidth()/2;
         var y = getWidth()/2;
         circleD.setPosition(x,y);
         add(circleD);

            var circleY = new Circle(eggRadius);
          circleY.setPosition(eggRadius/2,20);
          circleY.setColor(eggWhiteColor);
          var x = getWidth()/2;
          var y = getWidth()/2;
          circleY.setPosition(x-30,y-15);
          add(circleY);

              var circleI = new Circle(eggRadius);
          circleI.setPosition(eggRadius * 5,200);
          circleI.setColor(eggWhiteColor);
          var x = getWidth()/2;
          var y = getWidth()/2;
          circleY.setPosition(x-50,y-10);
          add(circleI);
```

I expected the circles to group together but they will not and I don't know what to do.

Comment: `var x` are you sure this is java? Is this a custom object/class you have made? If yes, please edit your question to include this.

Comment: @FailingCoder `var` has been a part of Java since Java 10: https://developer.oracle.com/java/jdk-10-local-variable-type-inference.html

Comment: Could you please include a note and screenshot if possible on the "Fried Egg Challenge"? Specifically, what the goal is and what your current result is.

Comment: Just by reading the code, there's probably an error at `circleY.setPosition(x-50,y-10)`, it should be `circleI.setPosition(x-50,y-10)`. However, I don't get why you set the position twice for each circle.